# Would not matter "for" or "to" most of us?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

I wanted to know which answer among these is grammatically more appropriate in context to the given situation:

> Question: Did you know there was a correction in one question in today's test?
>
> Ans 1. It would not matter for most of us. Our overall marks are very low.
>
> Ans 2. It would not matter to most of us. Our overall marks are very low.

Also, if both are correct when should I prefer the usage of one over the other?

Comment: Please see the [tag info for Prepositions questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/prepositions/info). In particular, we need to know what the sentence is supposed to *mean* in order to advise on correct prepositions.

Comment: @AndyT Possibly. It will be a duplicate, I'm sure, but they will be able to find the question to link it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*X would not matter for Y* and *X would not matter to Y* have slightly different meanings.

*X would not matter to Y* means Y doesn't care about X.

*X would not matter for Y* means X doesn't affect Y.  Y may still care about X, though.